# Desktop performance issues

Tags: hard-drive, memory, performance, cpu, desktop

I have a desktop tech specs

```
Core i5 / 12 GB RAM /
HD Seagate Barracuda ST500DM002 500GB 7200 RPM 16MB
```

The problem that my PC simply freezes or slow downs during of compilation code/... or whenever I run multiple OS.. I'm trying to figure out why. Right now I'm running VMware and Mac os as the guest machine.. the host machine is Linux(Ubuntu)(as you can see from screenshot below).The same performance issues are on windows as host machine
 I just tried to compile my android project as result my pc became unresponsive for a few minutes. I took screenshot in the moment of compilation.. it shows  that there is no system huge usage:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

**UPDATE:** Screenshot of CPU temperature during compilation:

[image]

As I can see the temperature is around 50 C..

Can anyone explain why it happens? I assume it 's the Hard Drive fault..but It's about 2.5 years(1 year 10 mo power on hours).. I can afford hardware upgrade. but I need to know exactly what I needs to be upgraded.

Thank you!

**Update:**  As Requested by  @Leathe here are results of executing  command which shows hard drive's read speeds:

```
/dev/sdb:
 Timing cached reads:   22754 MB in  2.00 seconds = 11386.87 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 388 MB in  3.00 seconds = 129.13 MB/sec
```

Comment: Can you paste the info you get from `hdparm -Tt /dev/sda` (or whatever it's named as)? It should show you the hard drive's read speeds.

Comment: Did this problem just start or has it always been doing this?
How many cores did you enable on the VM and how much RAM did you allocate to it? Just trying to narrow down the issue. (Edit: Ps. the hard drive read speeds seem to be normal)

Comment: This  problem occurs whenever I do some "hard core" stuff like launching the second VM.. or | compiling code(large project) along running VM  I allocate 4 GB of memory to the VM .. + all 4 cores of my processor.

Comment: Do you compile anything on the VM at all? All cores seem a bit excessive if it's not being used. Perhaps toning down on the cores for the VM could potentially work. The RAM amount is fine, could even be higher, but not really necessary.

Comment: Ah. So all or most development happens on the VM then? If that is the case, and you don't really have any stress on the host machine, you could actually add cores to the VM.

Comment: It's 50% done on VM and 50% on Host.. Sometimes I need to get work on both for convenience :)  Anyway.. I Got you  .. It's the CPU performance issue. I think 6 Core i7 is my next option or 12 core xenon.. :P..

Comment: If you compile on the VM and the host machine freezes, or vice versa, then the CPU might not actually be the problem here. It just seems too odd if you've split them 50/50 for the cores. However if the machine you're compiling on freezes, then I'm leaning towards the CPU being the bottleneck. (I'll add an actual answer once I get back from lunch)

Comment: @Leathe Thank you again. Enjoy your lunch. and Let's clear the comments section :)

Comment: I just hope you're not trying to run the android emulator inside the vm...

Comment: @jiggunjer I run android emulator in the host machine and iOS simulator inside the vm :)

Comment: First thing that came to my mind was that VM and emulator might both rely on virtualization technology. So try switching off that setting in your AVD if you have a VM running.

Comment: @jiggunjer What Visualization Technology has to do here. You mean it's number of dedicated CPU Cores?

Comment: I meant intel VT. Though it is only used when emulating x86, not ARM.

Comment: @jiggunjer Hey, Thank you  very much for your Input. I believe something could go wrong with my RAM memory Units. I noticed that my pc slows down(freezes) whenever Ram Usage  goes above 6gb  / Perhaps the second unit of Ram Memory malfunctioning or something like that. since I have 12 Gb memory. first  one is 7+ gb and the second one is about 4GB.. perhaps the second one is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see through a few possibilities that could contribute to the slowness and freezing.

**CPU being the bottleneck:**

In your case the issue could revolve around the allocation of CPU cores to the VM and how many are left for the host.

As you mentioned you've allocated 2 cores to the VM, meaning with your Intel i5 with 4 cores, you're left with 2 cores for the host. The host still has all 4 cores available, to all intents and purposes, but as long as the VM is under heavy load, the host is only really capable of using the remaining 2. However, in this case you're limiting the VM to 2 cores. It cannot use more than what it has been given.

If you are compiling a huge software on your VM, the 2 cores given to it might not be enough and it has to use effectively 100% of the processing power for that task (*assumption: both cores are used for compiling*). This causes all other software to act slow and even freeze the OS for a while, but only on the VM. The host shouldn't really be affected by this, which leads us to another possibility..

**Hard drive being the bottleneck:**

*(Ninjaedit: If you're running your VM on a different HDD that the host is on, this really shouldn't be an issue)*

The problem could also be in the hard drive. Not necessarily that the hard drive is damaged or getting old, but that the hard drive simply can't keep up with what it is supposed to be doing.

If you're running a VM on a hard drive and compiling on that same hard drive, while perhaps having additional tasks run on it from the host, this could potentially slow down everything because the hard drive just isn't fast enough, but not show up in the CPU usage.

**The Virtual Machine:**

The issue could also be at the VM end, if the settings are set up in an incorrect way that might cause a system freeze. The simplest way is to look at guides for the particular VM-software.

**In the end..** the reason could be anything. Any of the suggested scenarios or none, something completely different that might be overlooked.

My suggestion before diving into buying a new CPU (if money isn't an issue, then why not?) is to step by step see what part is slowing down the system. Check if there are any bad sectors on the hard drive, check if all cores of the CPU are being utilized while compiling  / doing other tasks. The list goes on.

Hope this helps at least a bit.

Comment: I believe it's the Hard Drive performance issue..  I think SSD is more suitable for hardcore development purposes so I've ordered one! :)